# Python script to get greater than 60 marks

Tags: python

I have a sets with student-name and marks inside list.

```
marks = [{"Rajesh", 76}, {"Suresh", 56}, {"Vijay", 62}]
```

I want to get greater than 60 marks from the above sets.

Result:

```
[{"Rajesh", 76},{"Vijay", 62}]
```

I have tried

```
marks = [{"Rajesh", 76}, {"Suresh", 56}, {"Vijay", 62}]
hi= [i for i in marks if list(i)[1]>60]
print(hi)
```

Comment: do you want to filter on list of sets?

Comment: Sets are not an appropriate data structure for storing the student name and mark data, can you change them to something else like a tuple or dict?

Comment: Sets are unordered structures so you can't use index to access an element. I'd just convert it to a list of lists. `marks_lists = [list(i) for i in marks]` And then use the resulting list of lists.

Comment: The order of values in sets is undefined. It's not guaranteed at all that `list(i)[1]` will refer to the mark.

Comment: Please read [ask] and **ask a question** when posting. Saying "I have tried <code here>" is not helpful, because it does not tell us: **what happened** when you tried running the code? **How is that different** from what you want? **What is your understanding** of that difference? **What do you need to know** in order to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using set data structures which is unordered. Change to tuple or list.

```
marks =[("Rajesh", 76), ("Suresh", 56), ("Vijay", 62)]
hi =[(i,j) for i,j in marks if j > 60]
print(hi)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue lies in using sets to represent student data. The order of elements in a set is not guaranteed. You may wish to use a list or dictionary that you can predictably index into.

```
marks = [["Rajesh", 76], ["Suresh", 56], ["Vijay", 62]]

above60 = [x for x in marks 
             for _, m in (x,) 
             if m > 60]
```